# Disabling highlighted search box

Tags: css, website-design, html5, css3

I made a search box using input html tag but while inputting when I click on the search box it is highlighted with blue border. How do I remove it ? 
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. It its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code it is hard to give you an exact answer, but it will be something like

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
outline: none;
}
```

But this covers your entire site, so you might want to be more specific using a class or ID if you only want to alter that specific field.